# Error on add_submenu_page() declaration

Tags: debug, add-submenu-page

Was called incorrectly. The seventh parameter passed to an `add_submenu_page()` should be an integer representing menu position. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 5.3.0.) in `/home3/prombooking/listandlink.com/wp-includes/functions.php` on line 4986

Answer (score 0):

You have to search for this function. It can be in theme or plugin. Last parameter for this function is an integer which determines where the menu should appear in wp-admin.

Answer (score 0):

his error message is indicating that there is an issue with the add_submenu_page function in your WordPress site. This function is used to add a submenu page to an existing top-level menu.

The seventh parameter of the add_submenu_page function should be an integer representing the position of the menu item in the menu. This value can range from 1 to 99, with lower numbers appearing closer to the top of the menu.

It looks like there may be an issue with the value being passed to this parameter. To fix the problem, you will need to locate the call to add_submenu_page in your code and ensure that the seventh parameter is a valid integer.